# How to post data controller in Laravel 5.4?

Tags: ajax, laravel, controller, laravel-5.4

I cannot post my data to my controller, is there something wrong with my ajax call? my setup for the web.php, or is the controller not setup, the error i get is. reminder this is laravel 5.4 running locally

POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/change-rank 500 (Internal Server Error)

JS

```
$('.rank-select').change(function(){
    var id = $(this).val();
    var memberId = $(this).closest('.irmember').attr('id');
    console.log(id);
    console.log(memberId);
    $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'change-rank',
                data: {id: id, memberId, memberId},
                success: function( msg ) {
                    console.log(msg);
                }
            });
})
```

web.php

```
Route::post('change-rank', 'RankController@changeRank');
```

RankController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Rank;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class RankController extends Controller
{
    public function changeRank()
    {
        info("hi");
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the `info()` function?

Comment: In Laravel it acts as a log, so i would see a "hi" in my log file if it was a success

Comment: Cool, didn't know `Laravel` has that function. What is the response you're getting in your network tab when you make the request? Failing that what error are you getting in your `laravel.log` (I would suggest clearing out the log first).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JS code you show does not include the CSRF token, which will certainly throw a 500 server error.  There are different ways to include your CSRF token in AJAX calls, here's one example.

**In your form:**

```
<form>
    {{ csrf_token() }}
    ....
```

**In your JS:**

```
var token = $('input[name="_token"]');
....
$.ajax({
    data: {_token: token, id: id, memberId: memberId},
    ...
```

There are [other approaches here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41867849/6089612), and the Laravel docs [suggest another method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/csrf).

BTW, `500 server error` is just a generic error telling you that, well, there was a server error.  You really need to know *what* the error was if you want to solve it - and you should be able to see that in both the laravel and webserver (Apache/nginx/etc) logs.  Your logs probably say something like "CSRF TokenMismatchException" which might have led you straight to the answer! :-)

**EDIT**

I've just noticed a typo in your Javascript which I initially copied into my answer.  It may just be a typo here and not in your real code as it would likely throw JS errors rather than run and generate server error.

```
data: {_token: token, id: id, memberId, memberId},
```

should be:

```
data: {_token: token, id: id, memberId: memberId},
```

(colon after `memberId`).

Answer (score 1):

Change your JS code like:

```
$('.rank-select').change(function(){
    var id = $(this).val();
    var memberId = $(this).closest('.irmember').attr('id');
    console.log(id);
    console.log(memberId);
    $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'change-rank',
                data: {id:id, memberId:memberId},
                success: function( msg ) {
                    console.log(msg);
                }
            });
});
```

Comment: @jeremy: Found any luck with this?

Comment: Hey, no, this is more a routing issue than adding a semi colon :/

Comment: And what was it?

Answer (score 0):

Its simple change to ajax params its should work fine.

```
$('.rank-select').change(function(){
    var id = $(this).val();
    var memberId = $(this).closest('.irmember').attr('id');
    console.log(id);
    console.log(memberId);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'change-rank',
        data: {id:id, memberId:memberId},
        success: function( data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

And controller file is,

```
public function changeRank(Request $request)
{
    return $request->all();
}
```